# Do forests increase atmosphere's oxygen?

Tags: environment

I've read that forests are important because they absorb carbon dioxide and release oxygen to the atmoshpere [1](http://blog.ontrac.com/bid/63022/Forests-Earth-s-Lungs). But other places say that this is false for a mature forest:

> "On average, then, this mature forest has **no net flux of carbon dioxide or oxygen** to or from the atmosphere, unless we cut it all down for logging," Sarmiento said. "The ocean works the same way. Most of the photosynthesis is counterbalanced by an equal and opposite amount of respiration." [2](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2004/06/0607_040607_phytoplankton_2.html)

It seems that phytoplakton are the responsibles of carbon dioxide fixing and oxygen emission.

> Tiny ocean plants called phytoplankton contribute 50 to 85 percent of the oxygen in Earth’s atmosphere.[3](http://earthsky.org/earth/how-much-do-oceans-add-to-worlds-oxygen)

So are there any solid studies that show what are the "lungs" of the planet, if any?

Comment: Is http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/6804/2703 a satisfactory explanation, or answer to your question?

Comment: one thing to note about a mature forest is that the trees will die fall and decompose and new ones will replace it, this will produce oxygen (or more accurately bind carbon)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Yes, this is the essence of the answer pointed to by ChrisW. I'm hoping we can close as duplicate.

Comment: Yes, mine's a duplicate. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @ratchetfreak My guess is that when the forests' total biomass is constant (e.g. when the planet's forests are mature and stable) then carbon and oxygen aren't affected either way. When the biomass is growing, as it did when plant-life first evolved and grew all over a previously-barren planet, that binds CO2 and produces O2 (more specifically, "produced" in the past tense). When the biomass is shrinking, as when humans deforestate, that releases CO2 and loses oxygen.

Comment: @ChrisW biomass increases in more subtle ways: dropped leaves and branches adding to the topsoil would be the one that comes to mind

Comment: @ratchetfreak I've heard that forests have little soil, and that any dead biomass (leaf litter) is consumed and recycled.

Comment: @jinawee No need to delete it. It will get closed as a duplicate, but leave it here as a signpost for search engines.

Comment: I've voted to close it as a duplicate, therefore.